# How to enable hotswap in Eclipse with SpringBoot 2.2.7.RELEASE (circa 2020)?

Tags: spring-boot, eclipse-plugin

Google is not cooperating on this one... most hits are at least 5 years old or using Tomcat.

How can I enable code hotswap in Eclipse (it says 2019-06 right now but I'll upgrade if needed) with SpringBoot 2.2.7.RELEASE (this was the latest version as of a few days ago, but I can upgrade to 2.3.0-RELEASE if needed)?

Comment: Are you launching your application using Run or Debug?

Comment: I tried both, same result

Comment: [`spring-boot-devtools`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/howto.html#howto-hotswapping) isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is all that's needed:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```